# Cant get the path of uploaded image in php

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the path of an image that I upload in the html page using php, but when i use the method $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'] it displays an error saying "undifined index: file1".
This is the code I am trying:
HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="GET" action="image.php">
<br/>
<input type="file" name="file1"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$files=$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$folder="images";
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']))
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $folder . '/'.$_FILES['file1']['name']);
    $image=$folder . '/'.$_FILES['file1']['name'];
    echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    echo $image;

  }
  else
  die("Not Uploaded");


?>
```

Comment: file upload requires `method="POST"`, but you are using `method="GET"`. Also, you need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` - see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Seems I was typing up my answer at about the same time of your comment Sean @Sean I didn't see it till I clicked on *"Post your answer"* while gathering a link and then some.

Comment: Same here @Fred-ii-. After I posted, I saw your answer popup.

Comment: @Sean the OP can choose either one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Uploading files require a POST method and not a GET.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Also make sure the folder you are wanting to upload to, has proper permissions to write to it.

Sidenote edit: Plus, as stated in the other answer, a valid enctype is required.

---

I'd also use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){...}
```

In order to ensure of a POST method, while using full bracing for your `else` and adding another `else{...}` for the above.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $files=$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="images";
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $folder . '/'.$_FILES['file1']['name']);
        $image=$folder . '/'.$_FILES['file1']['name'];
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
        echo $image;
    } else {
        die("Not Uploaded");
    }

} else{
   echo "A POST method was not used here.";
}
```

Also a conditional `!empty()` against your file input.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I forgot about the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that also needs to be added. Long day and close to suppertime, low sugar count ;-)

Comment: why was this suddenly downvoted, care to explain or you're just being a dick?  Merry Xmas to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<form name="form1" method="GET" action="image.php">
```

to

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image.php">
```

Comment: Lordie, I totally forgot about that `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. got my vote.

Comment: Sidenote: I rather the OP chooses your answer over mine, *cheers*